# ui-widget-overlay over dialog window

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, overlay

How to show ui-widget-overlay or something similar over dialog window. I'd like to disable dialog window(not hide) during ajax calls.

Also will be nice to show loading image at the center of disabled dialog window.

How it could be implemented via jquery ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [blockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

And use like `$.blockUI()` and `$.unblockUI()`.

If anything still pops over the overlay make sure you specify a high enough setting for `z-index` property while initializing the defaults for the plugin.